# Matlab checking if all vector elements == -inf

Tags: matlab, vector, equality, infinity

How do I do this? If I were checking for 1's I'd look at the length of the sum, but not sure how to check if all elements are equal to -infinity without looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `all` [doc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html)

```
v = [-inf, -inf, -inf, -inf]
all(v==-inf)

1

v = [-inf, -inf, 1]
all(v==-inf)
0
```